# How to prevent screenshot in IOS by using React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing an application in react-native. I just need to prevent screenshot in ios. I could make it in android by using expo-ScreenCapture but It does not work on IOS.
Here ı just need a way to prevent Screenshot on IOS. Any way that is related to the native is also OK for me such that using UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot

Answer (score 0):

**iOS**
overlay screen in `AppDelegate.m`, take this example:

```html
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {    
    // fill screen with our own colour
    UIView *colourView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
    colourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    colourView.tag = 1234;
    colourView.alpha = 0;
    [self.window addSubview:colourView];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:colourView];
    // fade in the view
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        colourView.alpha = 1;
    }];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // grab a reference to our coloured view
    UIView *colourView = [self.window viewWithTag:1234];
    // fade away colour view from main view
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        colourView.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // remove when finished fading
        [colourView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this solution can prevent screenshot ? I know when the app state is foreground the overlay screen is turning white but also works for screenshot ?

Comment: I didn't try, if you want, take your chance :)

Comment: I tried. I don't know if it's work on old iOS versions but doesn't prevent ScreenShot on iOS 11 and newer versions. Actually, this code makes application white blankscreen when app state is not foregrounded. There is no way to prevent screenshot on iOS, and has version of greater or equal than 11. But there is way to listen wheter screenshot taken or not. I solved it like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [ScreenShield](https://github.com/JayantBadlani/ScreenShield) SDK  in your React Native code.

I worked on an app where securing chat content was a requirement. After R&D, I concluded that preventing screen capture in an iOS app is not directly supported by the iOS operating system. However, we can customize our code to achieve the desired result.

As a solution, I created [ScreenShield](https://github.com/JayantBadlani/ScreenShield), a library designed to secure content by blocking screenshots and screen recordings. It provides a simple solution to protect your app's content. I hope it proves helpful for others facing the same challenge.

[Integrating ScreenShield SDK with React Native](https://github.com/JayantBadlani/ScreenShield/blob/main/README.md)

### HOW TO USE:

This guide explains how to integrate the ScreenShield SDK into your React Native project to protect your app from screen recording.

### Installation

1. Install the ScreenShield SDK through CocoaPods. Follow the installation instructions provided in the ScreenShield documentation.

#### Add this pod sdk in your podfile

```rb
    pod 'ScreenShield'
```

### Usage

#### 1. Add Swift File

Create a Swift file named `ScreenShieldRN.swift` under your iOS root directory with the following content:

```swift
import Foundation
import ScreenShield

@objc(ScreenShieldRN)
class ScreenShieldRN: NSObject {

    @objc func protectScreenRecording() {
        ScreenShield.shared.protectFromScreenRecording()
    }

    @objc static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

#### 2. Add Objective-C File

Create an Objective-C file named ScreenShieldRN.m and add the following code:

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import "React/RCTLog.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(ScreenShieldRN, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(protectScreenRecording)

@end
```

#### 3. Create a Bridge File

Create a bridge file named ScreenShieldRNBridge.h with the following code:

```objectivec
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
```

#### 4. Usage in React Native

Now, you can use the ScreenShield functionality in your React Native code. For example:

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { ScreenShieldRN } = NativeModules;

ScreenShieldRN.protectScreenRecording(); // Call the protectScreenRecording method to protect from screen recording
```

That's it! With just a few lines of code, you can protect your app's content and prevent it from being recorded or captured by unwanted screen capture mechanisms.